# square root of number of the form a + b*sqrt(c)

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

How can we compute the square root of a number `a + b*sqrt(c)` in sympy?

For example, we expect `sqrt(3 + 2*sqrt(2))` to be `1 + sqrt(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific function that does this is called `sqrtdenest`:

```
In [19]: from sympy import sqrt, sqrtdenest

In [20]: e = sqrt(3 + 2*sqrt(2))

In [21]: e
Out[21]: 
  __________
╲╱ 2⋅√2 + 3 

In [22]: sqrtdenest(e)
Out[22]: 1 + √2
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sqrtdenest

The `sqrtdenest` function is also used by `simplify` which is explained in the SymPy tutorial:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your question as it is not very detailed, but here is a link

[https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html\](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html%5C)

E.g.

```
>>> from sympy import simplify, cos, sin
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> a = (x + x**2)/(x*sin(y)**2 + x*cos(y)**2)
>>> a
(x**2 + x)/(x*sin(y)**2 + x*cos(y)**2)
>>> simplify(a)
x + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As @oscar-enjamin pointed out, `sqrtdenest` is a good first stop. I would also add that if you have a number that you think can be written in terms of other numbers, `nsimplify` might be able to help:

```
>>> from sympy import nsimplify, sqrt, divisors
>>> eq=sqrt(3 + 2*sqrt(2))
>>> nsimplify(eq,[sqrt(2)])
1 + sqrt(2)

>>> eq = sqrt(19 + 3*sqrt(2) + 6*sqrt(3) - sqrt(10))
>>> nsimplify(eq, [sqrt(i) for i in divisors(int(eq**2)) if i - 1])
-sqrt(2) - sqrt(6)/2 + sqrt(3)/2 + sqrt(5)/2 + 3/2 + sqrt(15)/2 + sqrt(30)/2
```

Comment: You can check that the results are the same by computing the `minpoly(result)` and `minpoly(eq)`. Note that `nsimplify` is an approximation routine.